# Can a irrealis form verb be combined with the adjective particle "な"

Tags: verbs, て-form, copula, particle-な

I asked this question because irrealis form and continuative form verbs can be combined with だ, so can't it be combined with na? I mean it looks ungrammatical but da goes with it so...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136825/discussion-on-question-by-star-peep-can-a-irrealis-form-verb-be-combined-with-th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called adjective particle な is only required for certain adjectives, and only when using that adjective **attributively** to directly modify a noun or noun phrase.  This form of the adjective + な is the so-called **連体形【れんたいけい】 ("attributive form")**, literally the "**form** (形【けい】) for **connecting** to (連【れん】) a **substantive** or non-inflecting word (体【たい】, from 体言【たいげん】 "substantive word").  The *rentaikei* for verbs is the same as the dictionary form, so there is no need for any linking particle to create the attributive form.

Where you see a verb with だ, you're usually seeing one of two things:

- `[VERB in dictionary form or ます form]` + です (or だ), or (more commonly) `[VERB]` + の (or ん) + です (or だ)
  This is a kind of explanatory construction.  Think of this as a bit like the English, *"it's that [someone] is [VERB-ing]"*.
- `[VERB in continuative (stem) form]` + です (or だ)
  The verb here is being used as a noun, a bit like English *"-ing"* forms.
  頼【たよ】る is a verb, *"to depend on someone"*, and 頼【たよ】り is both the continuative or stem form of the verb, and (perhaps more commonly) the noun, *"the person or thing depended upon"*.  When followed by だ・です, this 頼【たよ】り is unambiguously the noun.  Noun statements in Japanese require a だ or です afterwards to form a complete [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)).

There are cases where the 未然形【みぜんけい】 ("irrealis form", basically "hasn't happened yet") of a verb can be followed by な, so long as that な is the stem of the negative auxiliary (suffix) ～ない, and that な is followed by the correct ending for the syntax (such as ending in ～い for the terminal or attributive, or ending in ～く for the adverbial, or ending in ～かった for the past tense, etc.).

I cannot think of any case where the *mizenkei* of a verb can be followed by だ or です.

Comment: so mizenkei is like those conjugations

Comment: so kute is the te form.. (of an adj of course)